# best way to merge json files for pd dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have multiple json file which saved a response from Requests which contains 5 records per row/list like this

```
[{"Record1": "1", "Record2": "2", "Record3": "3", "Record4": "4", "Record5": "5"}]
```

Should I save it with resp.content which return without the array or resp.json() which is nested with array? What is the best practice?

What is the best way to put these together (approx 10k of files), so that I can put them in a pandas dataframe and further analyze? I tried to put it this and try to load with json.load(), but it comes back with a error: Extra Data

```
import json
import codecs
import glob

files = glob.glob('./results/*.json')

with codecs.open('combined_results.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for file in files:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        data = json.load(f)
        json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=None)
        outfile.write("\n")
```

Output:

```
[{"Record1": "1", "Record2": "2", "Record3": "3", "Record4": "4", "Record5": "5"}]
[{"Record1": "1", "Record2": "2", "Record3": "3", "Record4": "4", "Record5": "5"}]
[{"Record1": "1", "Record2": "2", "Record3": "3", "Record4": "4", "Record5": "5"}]
```

load the combined file into object: (error: Extra Data)

```
f = codecs.open('combined_results.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your code to merge your files into a valid json object:

```
combined_results = []
with open('combined_results.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for file in files:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        combined_results.append(json.load(f)[0])
    json.dump(combined_results, outfile)
```

Now to read this file in a dataframe try `pd.read_json`:

```
pd.read_json('combined_results.json')
```

**UPDATE:**

You don't actually need the `combined_results.json` file at all. Unless you want your files to be merged in a single file which you wish to use later, you can directly convert the list of `combined_results` into a dataframe.

```
combined_results = []
for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    combined_results.append(json.load(f)[0])

pd.DataFrame(combined_results)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. But how can I unpivot indivdual data into rows?

Comment: its working now! thanks buddy! but can you explain more on whether i should store json with or without the array?

Comment: No problem! :) I tried to edit my previous comment and deleted it by mistake. But glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.DataFrame.from_records('combined_results.json')`

Comment: combined_result.json has one list on every row instead of a single list